# The meaning of whipped through the mall

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'll cite a quote from the Godfather book by Mario Puzo:

> He pondered for a moment. "A couple of our people will come to stay
>   here". He saw her look of fright and said impatiently, "You don't have
>   to be scared, I just want them here. Do whatever they tell you to do.
>   If you wanna talk to me, get me on Pop's special phone but don't call
>   me unless it's really important. And don't worry." He went out of the
>   house.
>
> Darkness had fallen and the December wind *whipped through the mall*

I confused by the *whipped through the mall* phrase. What could it mean mean there? I guess `whip` means to move air flow quckly there. But about mall? What's that got to do with Sonny go through the street?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your take on *whip* is correct. For mall:

> **mall** *n.* a usually public area often set with shade trees and designed as a promenade or as a pedestrian walk

The area pictured below, located in Washington, D.C., is referred to as the *national mall*.
[image: National Mall]